# Error while Assigning Multiple Gesture Recognizers to AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Hello Guys im currently lost on this error, its my first time dealing with IOS and With Swift and although i have been able to use 1 gesture recognizer for a view i need to set multiples ones for any object ( component.control has an AnyObject type ), and when i run it and press the Button ( passed as an AnyObject Type) i get just this error in the appDelegate.swift  file

```
line 1: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{  //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x1)
```

any help will be apreciated! thx!

here is what i have
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    //gestures  
    let gesture_tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ComponentDetailViewController.ctrl_tapped(_:event:)));
    let gesture_pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ComponentDetailViewController.ctrl_pinched(_:event:)));
    let gesture_swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(ComponentDetailViewController.ctrl_swiped(_:event:)));
    let gesture_longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ComponentDetailViewController.ctrl_longPressed(_:event:)));
    let gesture_rotate = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target:self,action: #selector(ComponentDetailViewController.ctrl_rotated(_:event:)));
    let gesture_pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(ComponentDetailViewController.ctrl_panned(_:event:)));

    let ctrl = component?.control;

    ctrl!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture_tap);
    ctrl!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture_pinch);
    ctrl!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture_swipe);
    ctrl!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture_longPress);
    ctrl!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture_rotate);
    ctrl!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture_pan);

    gesture_tap.delegate = self;
    gesture_pinch.delegate = self;
    gesture_swipe.delegate = self;
    gesture_longPress.delegate = self;
    gesture_rotate.delegate = self;
    gesture_pan.delegate = self;


    component?.control = ctrl as? UIView;

    //component?.control!.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    //component?.control!.addGestureRecognizer(tap);
    viewDisplayComponent.addSubview((component?.control)! as! UIView);

}


//Gesture methods
func ctrl_tapped(ctrl: AnyObject, event:UIEvent){
    setMessage("TO_tapped");
}
func ctrl_pinched(ctrl: AnyObject, event:UIEvent){
    setMessage("TO_pinchedWithArgs")
}
func ctrl_swiped(ctrl: AnyObject, event:UIEvent){
    setMessage("TO_swipedWithArgs");
}
func ctrl_longPressed(ctrl: AnyObject, event:UIEvent){
    setMessage("TO_longPressedWithArgs");
}
func ctrl_rotated(ctrl: AnyObject, event:UIEvent){
    //logTextView.text += "Rotated";
}
func ctrl_panned(ctrl: AnyObject, event:UIEvent){
    setMessage("TO_pannedWithArgs");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/):

> The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following
>   signatures:
>
> - (void)handleGesture;
> - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
>     Swift translation:
>     handleGesture(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)

Yet, all your action methods have signatures with two arguments.  I am unsure how you were able to get one gesture recognizer to work.

> i get just this error in the appDelegate.swift file:
>
> > line 1: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{ 
> >     //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x1)

What about the top of the output in Xcode's debug area, i.e. where print() statements are output?